# Image not found in html override

Tags: overrides, template-override

I did an override for joomla core mod_menu.
But if I try to insert an image like this...

`<img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/image.png">`

... it didnt work. The side loads only the content of the menu without any styling. If I insert the direct link without any php it works. In my template `index.php` the same code works fine. 
Does somebody know how I can link to an image in an html override, without a hard coded url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may get an PHP error or warning. That would explain why you see the menu without styling. You should enable error reporting on your server to see these errors/warnings.

What is the value of `$this->baseurl` and `$this->template`? Are these variables really available in your override? You can check the values with PHP's var_dump() function:

```
<?php var_dump($this->baseurl); ?>
```

My guess is that these or at least one of these variables is null, because they are not defined. If I'm correct you can use this code to get your URLs:

```
<img src="<?php echo JUri::base(true); ?>/templates/<?php echo JFactory::getApplication()->getTemplate(); ?>/images/image.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
<img src="<?php echo JUri::root(); ?>/templates/<?php echo JFactory::getApplication()->getTemplate(); ?>/images/image.png" />
```